# Is it a coincidence that there are 4 fundamental interactions and 4 quantum numbers?

Tags: forces, atomic-physics, interactions

I can imagine that a system where each component has four defining characteristics would also have four ways those components can interact; the characteristics define interaction for each group. I think of it as each interaction is an equation where the characteristics are variables. A system of four scalar equations and four variables is nice and solvable.

Is this the case for the fact that there are four fundamental interactions and four quantum numbers for subatomic particles? Could we theoretically (or practically) define the interactions as equations of the four quantum numbers?

Comment: What do you think the 4 quantum numbers are?

Comment: It's a coincidence. Also, the number of interactions depends on the energy scale. At the electroweak scale, it falls to three. Reducing it further at even higher energies is speculative, but plausible.

Answer (score 1):

The number of quantum numbers is basically the number of dimensions of configuration space. For example, a single particle with spin (like an electron) can move in three spatial directions and in one internal dimension (spin): the 'four quantum numbers' you mention are simply the coordinates in these four dimensions. Note that these are not the four dimensions of space and time: if we take a particle without spin, it would only need three quantum numbers (despite still experiencing time). This shows that being described by 'four quantum numbers' is not at all a universal thing: it applies (for example) to single particles which have one internal degree of freedom, but not more generally, as you seem to imply.

Comment: Does this mean that in a system with a 2-dimensional configuration space you have only 3 quantum numbers? And in a 1-dimensional system you have only 2 quantum numbers?

Comment: For a single particle with spin $\frac{1}{2}$, yes.